# Finding XML files stored in exist-db on the file system in Linux

Tags: exist-db

I am running eXist-db in linux, but I am not able to find the XML files created  in the file system through linux commands like find command.  How can I see these XML files?

Answer (score 7):

eXist-db doesn't store XML documents directly on the file system - in the way you are describing.  It stores and manages them in database files in the $EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEB-INF/data folder.  If you want to access the XML documents, one way would be to mount the drive via WebDAV.  See eXist's [documentation on WebDAV](http://exist-db.org/exist/webdav.xml) or [search the mailing list archives](http://exist-open.markmail.org) for discussion about your particular WebDAV client if it's not covered in the documentation.